# HttpErrorResponse : when using HttpHeader in ionic 3

Tags: node.js, ionic3, angular5

I am using Ionic V3 , Angular V5.0.3 and for backend used Nodejs.

After login ,I trying to set header and pass the jwt-token via headers to backend so that I can authenticate user and sen response.

Code look likes in provider/userservice.ts,

```
import { HttpClient , HttpHeaders } from '@angular/common/http';

getUser(){
    this.token = localStorage.getItem('currentUser');
    console.log('In token is',this.token);
    let headers = new HttpHeaders().set('Authorization' , `${this.token}`);
    return this.http.get("http://localhost:3000/getUser", { headers })
        .do(res => console.log(res));
}
```

But after login I got an Error like,

**Failed to load http://localhost:3000/getUser: Request header field Authorization is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Headers in preflight response.**

I tried it many times but No Luck :(

Comment: You also walking into a trap with these line: this.token = localStorage.getItem('currentUser') as you are making an async call here and you believe you are getting token value right away, while in fact you need to do async/await OR Promise here to proceed with your call only when the value of the token was retrieved.

Comment: If you use Ionic's Storage you would do that this way: this.storage.get('token').then((value) => { this.token = value;}

Answer (score 0):

This is a CORS error, it’s server side. To fix you need to enable CORS and OPTIONS

Comment: I have added CORS header at server side

Comment: Thank you @Mike Tung its CORS as well as version issue of ionic. I solve it by adding  header **res.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "*");** on server side. and used HttpHeader on client side which solves my problem. In ionic v3 it uses HttpHeader instead of Header..:)

Comment: Please select as best answer and let’s be on our merry way :)